# Why does the markup bar on preview only display the "doodle" tool sometimes?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I feel like I'm going insane. In the markup bar on preview, there are "usually" two draw tools - the "sketch" one that autocorrects doodles to squares, arrows and ellipses, and the freehand "brush" tool (right).

I have opened two PDFs sent to me by the same person, both created using the same tool (iOS Version 16.5.1 (Build 20F75) Quartz PDFContext), both opened at the same time on my computer. A redacted screenshot of both open documents is shown below:

[image: only one preview window displays the freehand tool]

The freehand annotation tool (looks like a thicker squiggle) is only visible on one of the windows (circled).

1. What is causing this behaviour?
2. How can I make the freehand tool always visible?

I'm using Preview Version 11.0 (1033.4) on an M1 mac running macOS Monterey 12.6.6.